# Package Node.js app which runs as a service using node-windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-services, node-windows

I am using pkg to bundle the node application which uses node-windows to run it as a service. But the executable doesn't seam to start the service. I am not getting any error as well. Do we need add any additional configurations to the package.json to build?

Comment: Give some more information about what problem you are facing and what's your aim.

Comment: Have you tried running "npm link node-windows" in the project root first? Also showing the code would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding the following in your `package.json` file:

```
"pkg": {
    "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
    "assets": "views/**/*"
}
```